# Is it okay to mix $\iff$ and $\implies$ in a single derivation?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, article-writing

Say, I have to write down the steps to solve this equation $$ \frac{1 + ax}{a} - x = \frac{1}{a^2}(x - a). $$

Is the following manner a good way to write it?

\begin{align*}
\frac{1 + ax}{a} - x = \frac{1}{a^2}(x - a)
& \iff \frac1a = \frac1{a^2} (x - a) \\
& \implies a = x - a \\
& \iff x = 2a.
\end{align*}

The reason I went for $ \implies $ at the second step because we cannot divide $ a^2 $ on both sides of $ a = x - a $ to get the preceding step $ \frac1a = \frac1{a^2} (x - a) $ when $ a = 0 $.

Is it valid to mix $ \iff $ and $ \implies $ in a single derivation like this?

Comment: I mean, the question obviously has a built in caveat that $a \neq 0$, so if you have that condition in the beginning, you could replace it with double implications everywhere

Comment: Why shouldn't it be valid? One might argue whether it is a good idea communication-wise, but that's a wholly different question.

Comment: @celtschk What will be a better way communication-wise?

Comment: There is no issue with arguing $(A)\Leftrightarrow (B)\Rightarrow (C)\Leftrightarrow (D)$ (i.e. that $(A)$ coimplies $(B)$, and that $(B)$ implies $(C)$, and that $(C)$ coimplies $(D)$) specifically, so long that you do not start claiming having proved $(A)\Leftrightarrow (D)$.

Comment: @LoneLearner: For example, what Dhanvi Sreenivasan suggested. Or simply adding an $\ne 0$ to the last two equations so they are actually equivalent (as the original equation implies that $a\ne 0$), and then use $\iff$ throughout. Or if the backwards direction is not used later, simply write $\implies$ throughout. Or write it as you did, but add an extra sentence drawing attention to the fact that not all steps are equivalences.

Comment: Would be perfect if you had started with: "For $a\neq0$ we have ..."

Comment: Your $\implies$ can be replaced by $\iff$, because $a\ne0$ has to be stated at the outset (and it's bad not stating it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s okay if and only if every equivalence or implicication arrow is aligned and put on a separate line, like you did. This way, it will intuitively be understoood as a chain of equivalences or implications.

Not okay: “$A ⇔ B ⇒ C$” – now, did you maybe mean “$A ⇔ (B ⇒ C)$” or is it a chain?

Comment: Everybody would interpret this as a chain.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Only if it’s neatly written like that. Consider
$$x_0 ∈ C(f) \iff ∀ε > 0 ∃δ > 0 ∀x ∈X \colon \lvert x-x_0 \rvert < δ \implies \lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert < ε.$$
This is clearly not a chain. Now consider, within some proof where you want to conclude that $x = 0$ for some entity $x$ of which you have already shown some properties relating it to integers, a line like this:
$$x = 0 \iff x ≥ 0 \implies x^2 ∈ ℕ_0$$
Do you feel confident about what is meant here without any further context for how to interpret this? I say this is just bad proof-writing and should be avoided.